# Xcode8 storyboard how to set only one view controller in landscape?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8

the following picture show my question:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like my answer is not valid anymore, i guess you can just decorating your view in landscape mode alone for that screen :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there seems to be no way to solve this, i finally do the following to work around :
[image]

Comment: Me too was having the Question like you...finally did as you have done...its irritating.

Comment: I wonder why the heck this is unsupported directly, it is like taking away a feature.

Comment: @DeepakSharma yes，the orientation depend on the device, not the presentation in the storyboard.

Comment: So there is no way to force the root view controller to launch in landscape mode?

Comment: @DeepakSharma  of course it can . I have said the actual orientation depend on the device。so, if you want to launch in landscape, you should change the device orientaion ( e.g.: [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"] )  in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in appdelegate。and implement the -(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window method 。return the landscape orentation in that method。

Comment: Never works, moreover that force setting of orientation is something not documented and also doesn't works in iOS 10.